# Troubles looping through array with a form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to only put one username in the specific username tables.

Right now it is putting all usernames in the table.

The code:

```
$top_user_array = array('user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4');

$top_user_array = join("', '", $top_user_array);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ('{$top_user_array}')";
$send_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($send_query)) {
    $author = $row['username'];

    if(isset($_POST['create_sub'])) {

        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        $query = "UPDATE users SET user_subs = CONCAT(IFNULL(user_subs,''), '{$username}' ',') WHERE username = '{$author}' ";

        $create_user_sub = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        confirmQuery($create_user_sub);

        $query = "UPDATE users SET user_subscriptions = CONCAT(IFNULL(user_subscriptions,''), '{$author}' ',') WHERE username = '{$username}' ";

        $create_user_subscription = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        confirmQuery($create_user_subscription);

        echo "Subscribed";
    }

    echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="create_sub" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe To '. $author; echo ' <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>';
}
```

Basic example:

[image]

If "main user" subscribes to user1 it will put all users in "main users" user_subscriptions row instead of just putting the specific username there.

How the database looks after main user subscribes to user1

[image]

How it should **actually** look if main user subscribes to user1
[image]

After working with @Kodoyosa

This is the code that got my desired result:

```
$top_user_array = array('user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4');

$top_user_array = join("', '", $top_user_array);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ('{$top_user_array}')";
$send_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($send_query)) {
    $author = $row['username'];

    $author_u = str_replace(' ', '_', $author);    

    if(isset($_POST["create_sub_{$author_u}"])) {

        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        $query = "UPDATE users SET user_subs = CONCAT(IFNULL(user_subs,''), '{$username}' ',') WHERE username = '{$author}' ";

        $create_user_sub = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        confirmQuery($create_user_sub);

        $query = "UPDATE users SET user_subscriptions = CONCAT(IFNULL(user_subscriptions,''), '{$author}' ',') WHERE username = '{$username}' ";

        $create_user_subscription = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        confirmQuery($create_user_subscription);

        echo "Subscribed";
    }

    echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="create_sub_'.$author.'" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe To '. $author; echo ' <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>';
}
```

Comment: This would be far easier if you normalized subscriptions out into its own table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't answer the question if I say that this pattern is a bad idea and it would be more maintainable to separate `User` table and `Subscription` table

- `User` would only have users (id, username ...)
- `Subscription` would have the `subscriber` and the `subscribed_to`

So you can easily get Subs or Subscriptions for a user without creating duplicate infos

**BUT maybe you really have to go that way so just don't take this advice and let's try**

So your problem might come from the `if(isset($_POST['create_sub']))` which is true for every user (for every user the same verification).

Solution can be :

1. Add `name="create_sub_'.$author.'"` to your submit button
2. Check `isset($_POST["create_sub_{$author}"]` instead of just `if(isset($_POST['create_sub']))`

edit : have to use double quote for `isset($_POST["create_sub_{$author}"]` to use $author as a php variable

Comment: if(isset($_POST['create_sub_'$author])) brings back an error message saying unexpected '$author' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']'

Comment: sorry if(isset($_POST['create_sub_{$author}'])) should do the trick (I edit my answer)

Comment: no worries, I've tried it and nothing is being sent now. No users are being subscribed.

Comment: if it doesn't update and doesn't return errors so isset is always false. Can you var_dump($_POST); (anywhere I guess) and after submitting look for a "create_sub_user1" (if you click user1). The only guess I have is a typing error actually

Comment: If I do var_dump($_POST); after the if(isset($_POST['create_sub_{$author}'])) 

It brings back: array(1) { ["create_sub_user1"]=> under every subscribe button

Comment: If I put the var_dump($_POST); inside the if(isset($_POST['create_sub_{$author}'])) nothing comes back so it seems like the if(isset($_POST['create_sub_{$author}'])) isnt true?

Comment: I found the problem. Use double quote instead of simples  if(isset($_POST["create_sub_{$author}"])) just for this (simple quote will actually consider {$author} as a string). Sorry for that, I hope it will solve the problem

Comment: Awesome works great but for some reason, it doesn't work if there's a space in the username. For example "user one"

Comment: It comes from the fact that spaces in name variables are replaced by underscores. You're actually doing $_POST['create_sub_user one'] which miss the underscore. Maybe add before le line `if(isset($_POST["create_sub_{$author}"])) {` something like `$author_u = str_replace(' ', '_', $author);` then change `if(isset($_POST["create_sub_{$author}"])) {` by `if(isset($_POST["create_sub_{$author_u}"])) {`